# How do I change Unit in Windows Task Manager?

Tags: windows-8

The Windows Task Manager by default displays Network traffic in Mbps. How do I change it to some other unit?

Comment: The units actually autoscale dependent upon the values being measured.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you can change them  according to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151106093728/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/13/the-windows-8-task-manager.aspx) and [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=windows%208%20task%20manager), but as ernie said, they will scale.  But, the new task manager includes a "Heat map" feature, which basically color codes values in relation to each other, so you can check at a glance problems without having to pay attention to units.

[image]

As you can see, it includes network performance in the processes tab on the heat map.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, as Task Manager picks the most appropriate unit depending on the current performance.

Comment: I have a 512Kbps (bits) connection. Even when I'm downloading at full speed, all the tasks show 0Mpbs. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Anaty Are you sure you're looking at the right interface?

Comment: @ernie I am quite positive.

Comment: @Anaty Am I correct in understanding you're viewing the process tab and looking at specific processes?  Does the bandwidth get reported/recorded properly in the performance tab of Task Manager?

Comment: Aaah, I assumed the Performance tab ...

Comment: @ernie Yes your understanding is correct. I can't determine if the bandwidth is getting reported/recorded correctly as my connection speed is only 512 kbps, so even if a process is using the entire bandwidth, nothing is shown since the unit used to display is Mbps.

Comment: @Anaty - thanks for the response, but you didn't address the second portion.  Does the bandwidth show correctly in the Performance tab?  I've got a system with a 1000Mbps GigE connection locally, but the network Performance graph scales to where the max is 100 Kbps when idle.

Answer (score 1):

You can only select a set value (Mbps) or percentage, right click on the Network column header.

[image]